# Dart - cannot get firstWhere to throw exception on no match

Tags: dart

I am sure this is a simple syntax issue but...

Why does this test throw an exception?
I expected it to only throw an exception when it could not find any matches.

```
solo_test( "", (){
  List<String> lines = ["aa=1", "bb=2" ,"cc=3"];

  String line = lines.firstWhere((String line) => line.indexOf("bb") == 0, orElse: throw "could not find 'bb'");
  expect( line, equals( "bb=2"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
solo_test( "", (){
  List<String> lines = ["aa=1", "bb=2" ,"cc=3"];

  String line = lines.firstWhere((String line) => line.indexOf("bb") == 0, orElse: () => throw "could not find 'bb'");
  expect( line, equals( "bb=2"));
});
```

Comment: As a side note, `line.startsWith('bb')` could also be used here

Comment: Okay, so I needed to pass a function as the OrElse parameter. But why didn't the compiler complain that  'throw "could not find 'bb'"' is not a function?

Comment: Because it's a valid syntax ;-)

Comment: @richard It didn't throw because `orElse` is only executed when no element was found, but with the given criteria, an element is found and therefore no exception.

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
(String line) => line.indexOf("bb") == 0
```

the second element is found, therefore not `orElse` is executed.
And as @Robert mentioned you need to add `() =>`